# Laravel - Return All Posts Except some post with Condition

Tags: jquery, laravel, collections

i want to get posts but not that post with specific key value

i use below code for get my posts

```
$col = Post::where('type', $type)->whereNotIn('restrict', ['res1'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(24);
```

it's work but it also not return posts with **null** restrict value

how i get posts **Except** some of theme with restrict key value == 'res1'  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not return null value because you used whereNotIn. This means that it will return only rows that have value except 'res1' and null. So, Whenever you are applying a condition the mysql thinks that the field must not be null.

To overcome this situation use following way

```
$col = Post::where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotIn('restrict', ['res1'])->orWhereNull('restrict');                  
    })->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `where` with a `!=` operator.

```
$col = Post::where('type', $type)->where('restrict', '!=' , 'res1')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(24);
```